# How to hide Native Base modal status bar?

Tags: react-native, native-base

**Native Base version 3.3.10**

When I open native base modal, the status bar appears again. Even though I have set the status bar to hidden.

[Here is my code](https://snack.expo.dev/@pk936/moody-toffee)